# During an x86 software interrupt, when exactly is a context switch made?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu, interrupt

I am asking this because I am trying to implement interrupts in my toy kernel. So, I know that when an interrupt occurs, the CPU pushes various bits of information onto the stack. However, everywhere I search online shows different information in different order being pushed. I also know that if the interrupt occurred in user mode (Ring 3), the CPU must switch to kernel mode (Ring 0) before it can execute the ISR. I think it has something to do with the `TSS` and `ss` and `esp`, however I am not sure. I have read various different explanations all over the internet and have not found any uniformity in any of them yet.

So **my question is,** in what **exact** order does the (x86) CPU push data onto the stack during an interrupt and when does it do it, and at what point in time does it make a context switch via the `TSS` and how does this affect the data that is pushed onto the stack, if at all?

**What I have learned from research so far (correct me if wrong):** I am pretty sure the processor pushes `eflags`, `cs` and `eip` onto the stack as well as an `error code` if necessary during an interrupt. However, is this all that is pushed? I have read elsewhere that `ss` and `esp` are pushed but I don't know if this happens all the time, or **why** it is pushed.

Furthermore, I believe that the CPU will look in the `TSS` for the Ring0 `ss` and `esp` and **at some point** load them, but I am not sure when. Perhaps it does this right after the interrupt occurs? Also, how is `cs` and `ds` handled during all of this? Is `cs` loaded by the CPU from the entry in the `IDT`? What about `ds`? Must I load that manually?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, I am not sure where else I should.

Comment: Don't trust random things on the internet. Use the official manuals:  _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1, CHAPTER 6 INTERRUPT AND EXCEPTION HANDLING_

Comment: @Jester : Should we trust random people posting unofficial comments directing them to official information? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the [Intel Manual 3](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) and read:

- *Chapter 6 INTERRUPT AND EXCEPTION HANDLING*
- *Section 5.8.5 Stack Switching*
- *5.8.6 Returning from a Called Procedure*.

---

This is what is pushed on an interrupt

[image: ISR stack]

Keep in in mind that interrupt are handled with *Task Gates*, *Trap gates* and *Interrupt gates*, each one with different semantic and the last two very close to *Call gates*.